# simple grouping with php while loop?

Tags: php, while-loop

I am outputting a table of rates.  Each rate period has a Daily Rate and a Weekly rate, but the rate PERIODS remain the same.

So I am attempting to change the background color after ever TWO sets.  So basically, the table will show:

```
Date 1 - Weekly Rate
Date 1 - Daily Rate
<change bg color>
Date 2 - Weekly Rate
Date 2 - Daily Rate
<change bg color back to original>
```

At the moment, I have two styles set up for background colors in my stylesheet.   And the code i am using is giving me ALTERNATING rows.   I just cannot see why it's changing every one, instead of every OTHER one!

To do this, I MUST compare one Date1 to Date2.  ( I cannot make it change every two iterations, for reasons I do not want to go into.)

Here is my code so far inside the while loop.  Help! And thank you.

```
if ($previous !== $row[datefrom])
{       
    $thecolor = "bg1";
} 
else 
{
    $thecolor = "bg2";
}

echo "<tr class=\"".$thecolor."\"> \n";
echo "<td>" .  $row[datefrom] . " - " . $row[dateto]. "</td> \n";
echo "<td>" .  str_replace(" 3-5","",$row[Ratetype]) . "</td> \n";
echo "<td>$" .  $row[Rate] . "</td> \n";
echo "</tr> \n";

$previous = $row[datefrom];
```

Comment: Where is the question? what did you want us to help you with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also have to remember last used background color, without it background will change only for first entry in group. Example:

```
$use_original_bg = TRUE;

for(/*...*/){
    if ($previous !== $row[datefrom]) {
        $use_original_bg = !$use_original_bg; 
    }
    $thecolor = $use_original_bg?"bg1":"bg2";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We can see the reason for this very easy if we set up the states of *current date* and *prev* for each iteration:

```
 1. date1, prev = nothing => bg1
 2. date1, prev = date1   => bg2
 3. date2, prev = date1   => bg1
 4. date2, prev = date2   => bg2
```

One easy way to solve this problem is to also take into account the state of the background. I'll leave that up to you to give it some thinking.

Comment: Ahhh I'm with ya.  So if my dates do not match with my first if statement, I should set flag to also say the backgrounds will not be equal.  Then I set my color based on the BACKGROUND, not the actual date condition. This what you're getting at?  :)